# Python: access variable in a function in another file

Tags: python, variables, import, global, local

I have two files:

**lib.py**

```
global var
def test():
    var = "Hello!"
    return
```

**test.py**

```
from lib import *
test()
print(var)
```

But despite having them in the same folder, when I run test.py, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(var)
NameError: name 'var' is not defined
```

How can I access this variable in a function in another file?

Comment: Instead of using globals, why not have that function return a value, which you can save?

Comment: You can't access the variables in functions, unless you return them or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following:

**lib.py**

```
def test():
    return "Hello!"
```

**test.py**

```
from lib import *
var = test()
print(var)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!


I can see why you've done this, as it follows the intended use of variables much more closely.


However, what I should have explained that the problem I outlined above is a simplified version.


in one file, I have pygame code in a function such as:


`screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))`


And I am trying to access this by utilising it in another file:


`pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, 175, 130, 60, red_on)`


As such, am I correct in thinking that I could not use the return functionality to achieve this?

Comment: Okay, I tested it, turns out your solution still works! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the variable as global in the scope which it is used, which in this case is the function `test()`:

```
def test():
  global var
  var = "Hello!"
```

Note that the final `return` is not necessary, since it is implicit at the end of a function. Also, `var` is declared in the global scope of the module, so it won't be imported automatically by `from lib import *` since it's created *after* the module has been imported.

Returning `var` from the function is probably a better solution to use across modules:

```
def test():
  var = "Hello!"
  return var

var = test()
print(var) # Hello!
```